# Why does this docx-processing code not work/compile?

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I have this code, which processes a Word `docx` file:

```
void bookmarkReplace(BookmarkStart bms, Dictionary<string, string> values )
{
    foreach( var key in values)
    {
        string bookmarkName = bms.Name;
        if (bms.Name.Equals( key.Key))
        {

            bms.InsertBeforeSelf<BookmarkStart>(new Run(new Text(key.Value)));
            bms.Remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and it does not even compile . The `InsertBeforeSelf` gives an error: "has some invalid arguments", because before the `BookmarkStart`, you may not insert other types than `BookmarkStart`. Weird. Why would that be ?
My Word `docx` file shows a `<w:pRr>` element before a `BookmarkStart` element:

```
<w:p w14:paraId="49842CE1" w14:textId="1248047E" w:rsidR="000C7F1A" w:rsidRDefault="000C7F1A" w:rsidP="00BB4EA3">
    <w:pPr>
       <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
       <w:jc w:val="right"/>
       <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
       </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="17" w:name="FlexLV"/>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="17"/>
</w:p>
```

Any suggestions as to how to solve this problem of replacing a `BookmarkStart` with a text `run`?
btw: later in the program, I remove all `BookmarkStart` and `BookmarkEnd` elements.

Comment: What error do you got?

Comment: "has some invalid arguments"

Comment: You'll need to tell more about your problem. Take a look here: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InsertBeforeSelf` is generic with the generic type `T` being the type of the *new element* that you are inserting, *not* the type of the element you are inserting it before. This line:

```
bms.InsertBeforeSelf<BookmarkStart>(new Run(new Text(key.Value)));
```

is saying you want to insert a `BookmarkStart` before `bms` and the `BookmarkStart` you wish to insert is a `new Run`. Clearly a `Run` is not a `BookmarkStart` so you get a compile error:

> cannot convert from 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run' to 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.BookmarkStart'

The fix is easy enough, you need to define the generic type as a `Run` as that's what you're actually inserting:

```
bms.InsertBeforeSelf<Run>(new Run(new Text(key.Value)));
```

Simpler still, you can forgo the type altogether and let the compiler infer it from the parameter:

```
bms.InsertBeforeSelf(new Run(new Text(key.Value))); //the compiler infers that T is a Run
```